# Creating an intent inside child activity rather than parent activity while starting an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, optimization

What is the difference in terms of perfomance and optimization if while starting an activity i create an intent inside Child Activity(Activity to be started) rather than in parent Activity(Activity which is starting an new activity).

Example-

ChildActivity.class

```
public static Intent createIntent(Context context) {
    return new Intent(context, ChildActivity.class);
}
```

ParentActivity.class

```
     startActivity(ChildActivity.createIntent(ParentActivity.this));
```

Is it a good practice?Will this approach have any advantage if same activity is being started from multiple activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use that practice, so that we can start an `Activity` from any activities by calling a static method, we will save a lot of duplicate code. For me, I create a Navigator class, this class will store all methods which start activity:

```
public class Navigator {
    public static final String VENUE_EXTRA = "venue_extra";

    private Navigator() {

    }

    public static void navigateToOnboarding(Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, OnboardingActivity.class);
        ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, null);
    }

    public static void navigateToSharing(Activity activity, Venue venue) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SharingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(VENUE_EXTRA, venue);
        ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, null);
    }

    public static void navigateToAppSetting(Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + activity.getPackageName()));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Please explain how will it saves lot of duplicate code?Even if we are creating intent inside static method everytime an activity is started new intent is being created?

Comment: He is referring to effective length of code, for every start of the activity, you only need 1 line of code, not 3-4-5 or however many arguments you have in an intent(in every place you start the activity from). Performance wise it's the same. It is a best practice for readability.

Comment: @dzsonni Even without this i can start activity in one line with arguments.   `startActivity(new Intent(ParentActivity.this, ChildActivity.class).putExtra("key","value").putExtra("key","value"));`

Comment: And what part of that is considered readable code? Will you create lines hundreds of characters long? I don't think that code would get through any proper code reviewing process. Your code doesn't only have to be functional it also has to be easily readable. As I said before, your idea works, but it is ugly :)